# PDFBOX: how to create complex pdf acroform template or fill form pdf

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I want to create a complex pdf acroform or fill form as in term of pdfbox.

This pdf will contain a lot of images with tables, pie chart and many more component.

I have took a acroform from internet and tested it like setting the values at run time in static acroform pdf.

**But I didnt see much information on how I can create a pdf acroform template ? I can see information on how to get fields and set the fields.**

What I can figured by googling it. Different approaches.

- We can use acrobat to create acroform but it is paid service.cant use it.
- Create an acroform using java code but it is very tricky process.
- Create word document and fill the form and then convert in into pdf.- not sure how this will work.

  **Can anyone suggest for creating very complex acro form template ? Like any freeware tool or word to create or java is the only way to create it.**

Comment: PDFBox is a java tool, so your question kindof contradicts itself.

Comment: Can we create acroform template directly like some kind of drag and drop .. or is there additional tool for that

Comment: No there isn't.